# Scala Parser Combinator to match element from list

Tags: scala, parsing

I want a parser that matches if and only if the parsed String is contained by a given list of Strings.

```
def box: Parser[String] = // match if token is element of boxSyms: List[String]
```

Even after hours of searching the web, I have no idea how to achieve this. (Which makes me think I've looked for it the wrong way).

Edit:

This is only a snippet from a bigger parser. The input is going to be used in further parser combinators:

```
lazy val boxModal = box ~ formula  ^^ {
  case boxSym ~ formula => Box(boxSyms.get(boxSym).get, formula)
}
```

The problem is that the List boxSyms is unknown at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking for, but something like `boxSyms.map(literal).reduce(_ | _)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
lazy val boxModal = box ~ formula  ^^ {
  case boxSym ~ formula if boxSyms.contains(boxSym) => 
    Box(boxSyms.get(boxSym).get, formula)
}
```

Or some other, more specific condition.

Comment: Wouldn't the problem still be that I'd have to define box or am I missing something?

Comment: @wignode Where do the boxSyms come from, doesn't matter. It can be a mutable list.